# how to accept string empty in graphql validator

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs

when I send this,

```js
{
    firstname: "Ven",
    lastname: "",
 }
```

lastname return error
but when send

```js
  {
    firstname: "Ven",
 }
```

it doesn't error

```js
@InputType()
export class EmailFinderSingleRq {
    @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
    firstname: string;

    @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
    lastname: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution of my issue, I used JOI in nodejs it blocked string empty.

I just add min(0)

```js
lastname: Joi.string().min(0),
```